# How to search Windows 10 for ANY occurrence of a word?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, search

I never heavily used the search feature on Windows 7, so I don't know if the issue persists on versions outside of 10.

I'm trying to search through a lot of files using Windows' file browser search function. The problem is, when I search for something, it only shows files with the keyword at the beginning of a word or immediately after an underscore.

For example, I search for the word "cat". These would be the results:

- **Cat**egory.zip
- Picture of a **Cat**.jpg
- my_first_**cat**.txt

However, it wouldn't bring up words like "edu**cat**ional" or "appli**cat**ion", because the keyword is in the middle of that word. Is there a way to search for *all* occurences of a keyword in Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How to search Windows 10 for ANY occurrence of a word?**
>
> I'm trying to search through a lot of files using Windows' file
>   browser search function. The problem is, when I search for something,
>   it only shows files with the keyword at the beginning of a word or
>   immediately after an underscore.

The Windows Explorer search function way. . .

- Press <kbd>**Windows Key**</kbd> + <kbd>**E**</kbd>
- Press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**F**</kbd>
- Type in `*cat*` in the search field and press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>

  - Just put your keyword between two asterisks [`*`] `*cat*`

[image]

Comment: This works, but interestingly, it searches the file content too.  How do you do this with just filenames?

Comment: @cowlinator Check the other answer for command line method that will search for files only then e.g. `dir /s /b "C:\Folder\*cat*"`

Comment: ah, so it's not possible with windows explorer

Comment: @cowlinator Oh, I just reread what you were asking, you can use something like `name:*cat*` so just prefix the search value with `name:` and that should ensure that only the file names are searched and not the content. I use PowerShell or cmd for searches I do like this more than the File Explorer search function. Read over https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference for more detail on this functionality. Sorry about that, I thought you were just wanting a quick way to get it done rather than is it possible. Good luck with your tasks!

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt in the folder, then type:

```
dir /s /b *cat*
```

and replace cat with whatever you want. This will search all subdirectories of the current directory.

Comment: This is much better than windows search.  Faster and more accurate.  Please note that you have to be at the root (use `cd \`) of the drive to search the whole drive.  To search multiple drives, you will have to run it multiple times (once for each drive).

Answer (score 0):

For a GUI based solution, I highly recommend using [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack) for this purpose. I have not had much luck using the built-in search features of Windows since Windows 7, but Agent Ransack provides many more powerful options for searching the contents and names of files.

Answer (score 0):

Windows search will only show you lists of prefix words so it is normal that it will show those lists of categories.